# Simple React Redux state returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, store, redux-reducers

I am completely stumped on this one. I've built the simplest of simple react redux component that currently only shows a counter held in the store. However this counter is always returned as undefined!

I'd expect the counter to return `0` as this is what's set in the reducer!

I've followed countless tutorials and I'm getting no where!

```
//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import counterReducer from './reducers/counterReducer';

const store = createStore(counterReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and

```
//app.js

import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'; 


function App() {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{`counter is ${counter}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and

```
//actions.js

export const add = (nr) =>{
    return {
        type: 'ADD',
        payload:{
            nr
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
//counterReducer.js

const counterReducer = (state=0, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "ADD":
            return state+1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default counterReducer;
```

So as you can see it's a real simple setup. I'd expect the counter to return `0` as this is the initial state set in `counterReducer.js`

However I just get "counter is undefined" on the frontend!

Comment: Isn't `state` a number for you? `const counter = useSelector(state => state)`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @Federkun! That's fixed it! I knew it was bound to be something simple!! I really appreciate it!

Comment: or `rootReducer = combineReducers({counter: counterReducer})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either remove `.counter` from state

```js
// already a number
const counter = useSelector(state => state)
```

---

or add `counter` to your redux root object:

```js
import {createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import counterReducer from './reducers/counterReducer';

const store = createStore(combineReducers({counter: counterReducer});
```